# Google cloud load balancing puzzle

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-balancing

I have deployed a basic Wordpress site on GCP using the Google click to deploy package. The final aim is to create an autoscaling, autohealing, loadbalanced setup.

Using the Wordpress deployment, I create an image.

Using this image, I create an instance template.

Using this instance template I create an instance group.

I configure the instance group to autoscale, and create a health check for it to autoheal. Then I use an HTTP loadbalancer to distribute traffic. All of this is working perfectly.

However, if I delete/stop the initial Wordpress deployment, the first VM from which I created the image, the site stops working. Why is that so? The initial deplyment doesn't take any traffic, any changes I make to that deployment by going through the specific IP don't reflect on the site either.

It seems odd to have to pay for a VM that doesn't take any load, and doesn't seem to do anything much at all.

Comment: In what way does the site stop working? What are you doing to test it, and what error do you see?

Comment: Can you share some more information about the issue you are having:    What errors do you see? Can you share your Autoscaler configuration setup?